# nosql wishlist models - Struggle between reference and embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, nosql

I got a question about modeling wishlists using mongodb and mongoose. The idea is I need a user beeing able to have many different wishlists which contain many wishes, each wish making a reference to a single article

I was thinking about it and because a wishlist only belong to a single user I thought using embedded document for that.

Same for the wish beeing embedded to a wishlist.

So I got something like that

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
...
   wishlists: [wishlistSchema]
...
})

var WishlistSchema = new Schema({
...
    wishes: [wishSchema]
...
})
```

but my question is what to do with the article ? should I use a reference or should I copy the article's data in an embedded document.

If I use embedded document I got an update problem. When the article's price change, to update every wish referencing this article become a struggle. But to access those wishes's article is a piece of cake.

If I use reference, The update is not a problem anymore but I got a probleme when I filter the wish depending on their article criteria ( when I filter the wishes depending on a price, category etc .. ).

I think the second way is probably the best but I don't know how if it's possible to build a query to filter the wish depending on the article's field. I tried a lot of things using population but nothing works very well when you need to populate depending on a nested object field. ( for exemple getting wishes where their article respond to certain conditions ).

Is this kind of query doable ?

Sry for the loooong question and for my bad English :/ but any advice would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience in dealing with NoSQL database (mongo, mainly), when designing a collection, do not think of the *relations*. Instead, think of how you would *display, page,* and *retrieve* the documents.

I would prefer embedding and updating multiple schema when there's a change, as opposed to doing a ref, for multiple reasons.

1. Get would be fast and easy and filter is not a problem (like you've said)
2. Retrieve operations usually happen a lot more often than updates and with proper indexing, you wouldn't really have to bother about performance.
3. It leverages on NoSQL's schema-less nature and you'll be less prone restructuring due to requirement changes (new sorting, new filters, etc)
4. Paging would be a lot less of a hassle, and UI would not be restricted with it's design with paging and limit.
5. Joining could become expensive. Redundant data might be a hassle to update but it's always better than not being able to display a data in a particular way because your *schema* is normalized and joining is difficult.

I'd say that the rule of thumb is that only split them when you do not need to display them together. It is not impossible to join them back if you do, but definitely more troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I started using mongodb thinking it was the ultimate weapon for data but actually it's a trade off compare to an sql database. Anyway I slowly understand the spirit of nosql and the document way to handle data. I will do like you suggest and find a way to update in the most efficient way the embedded article. Thx